# Wordpress job survey plugin that e-mails the results to the admin

Tags: wordpress

One of my clients wants me to replace their survey with something they can change and that e-mails them. They are currently running their website on WordPress.
Their current survey is the following link and was made by some 3rd party company (which went out of business or something).
https://aplus50.com/individuals/

The biggest problem I'm finding is finding one that can give results for each person that uses this.

Comment: You could use a plugin like [Contact form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and create a form for each survey.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at that whenever the client green lights me.

Comment: @Howlin Answer the question so I can mark you as the person that answered it, and you can get your points.
Thanks a billion

Comment: Okay, but I will write a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin like [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and create a form for each survey.

Surveys will generally have dropdown lists, checkboxes and a text area, Contact Form 7 has all of these accessible in the Generate Tag list:

[image]

So the three options mentioned above would be added to the form like:

```
Dropdown list: [select rating "Brilliant" "Good" "Bad"]<br>
Checkbox: [checkbox rating2 "Brilliant" "Good" "Bad"]<br>
Any other information?: [textarea otherinformation]

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

and it would display on the website as follows:

[image]

In the mail section of the Edit Contact Form, you can specify how it will display on the email, e.g.

```
Someone has filled out your survey, here is there answer:
Rating: [rating]
Rating2: [rating2]
Other information: [otherinformation]
```

Where the text in the square brackets `[]` is the text name of the tag created earlier.